# formControlName with or without brackets?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

what is the difference between using `formControlName` inside brackets and without brackets? In the dynamic form tutorial `formcontrolname` is used inside brackets

```
[formControlName]="dyncontrol.key"
```

but in other tutorials i have seen it without them

```
formControlName="name"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's from the [Template Syntax documentation](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-to-a-property):

> ###Remember the brackets
>
> The brackets tell Angular to evaluate the template expression. If we forget the brackets, Angular treats the string as a constant and initializes the target property with that string. It does not evaluate the string!
>
> Don't make the following mistake:
>
> ```
> <!-- ERROR: HeroDetailComponent.hero expects a
> Hero object, not the string "currentHero" -->
> <hero-detail hero="currentHero"></hero-detail>
> ```

Comment: So the answer is "it depends." Thanks. Trying to work with a head cold, here, and thinking is difficult. Your answer has saved me from wasting a lot of time!

Comment: @cartant you see in the question where there are no brackets. The _string_ value `name` is going being used. If it had brackets, it would instead look for a _property_ named `name` from the component. In the example from the question where the brackets are used, if there were no brackets, the it would just use the _string_ `dyncontro.key` instead of the component property

Answer (score 10):

Using brackets means the value is an expression, without brackets, the value is a string:

```
let a = {n: "name"};
```

Then `[formControlName]="a.n"` is the same with `formControlName="name"`.

All the other angular2 attributes have same regular.

Answer (score 0):

with brackets it is a property binding:

```
[viewTargetProperty]='componentMember'
```

without brackets it is an input member of a component or a directive:

```
<p appHighlight highlightColor="yellow">Highlighted in yellow</p>
```

`highlightColor` is an input of the directive `appHighLight`.

So, for `formControlName` it an input of `FormControlName` directive.
It could be something like:

```
<input FormControlName formControlName="nameOfFormControlObject">
```

See the api documentation of FormControlName: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName. You will notice that it has an input called "formControlName" that is what we used here.

But somehow, FormControlName directive is not seen on the implementation. Somehow, it must be internally linked to FormGroup directive on the parent form:

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div *ngIf="first.invalid"> Name is too short. </div>

      <input formControlName="first" placeholder="First name">
      <input formControlName="last" placeholder="Last name">

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

I beg some expert clarifies the internals of this technique.

Comment: _"without brackets it is an input member of a component or a directive"_ - With or without brackets, it is an input property. With brackets, it is evaluated as a component/directive property. Without the brackets, it is evaluated as the constant string. That's all there is to it. Your answer is very misleading and incorrect.